# LINQ to Entities - Dynamic select for specify columns

Tags: entity-framework, select, dynamic, linq-to-entities

I can create a select query that retrieves only the specific columns (static in code) for LINQ to entities

```
from Example in new Enities.Table 
select new { Example.Column1. Example.Column2, ... }
```

But I can´t figure out how to select Column1, Column2 dynamic (e.g. from string[]). Thanks

Comment: +1 for the code, I was using Linq to entities and only wanted to pick the fields that I would bind to DataGridView and that worked for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard LINQ doesn't support that - you must download library called [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) or build expression tree manually. Dynamic LINQ will allow you to call queries like:

```
var query = Entities.Table.Select("new(Column1,Column2)");
```

But by using dynamic approach you will lose the main reason for using LINQ - compile time checking. You can in the same way use [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387118.aspx) instead of LINQ and build your queries from strings.