# Use Expression like Func

Tags: c#, expression

I need to get selector using expression which has source and destination, like mapper (I need it for EF).

```
public class Region
{
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
}

var country = new List<Region> { new Region { RegionId = 21, RegionName = "MyRegion" } };
Expression<Func<Region, string>> exp = (x => x.RegionName);
country.Select(s => exp(s));
// exp(s) gives compilation error (Method name expected)
```

Is it possible to get it?

Comment: Try writing with *country.Select(exp)* only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine this:

```
var items = new List<int>();
Expression<Func<int, int>> selector = (x => x);
```

You cannot do this because it is an `Expression`:

```
selector(x); // will not work
```

But this will work because you are compiling the expression so now you can call the `Func<int, int>`:

```
selector.Compile()(1);
```

And if you want to use the expression in a `IQueryable`, you can do this:

```
items.AsQueryable().Select(x => selector);
// Or simply
items.AsQueryable().Select(selector);
```

So in your case, it should be:

```
country.Select(exp);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, you wrote is the right answer. But, as I wrote, I need expression to use. I have much hard task to do, this is simple code up here. In my code I have Expression written, which gets RegionName from Select's "s" (my code is like this: class -> Car and need to get car info -> Select(s => s.CarOwnerName + " - " + myExpression(s.Model))), where "myExpression" gets ModelName + MakerName.. And I can't put that s.CarOwnerName into myExpresssion, cause in my code, it is huge too. Is it possible, to "Use Expression like a Func" for some extra selects..?

Comment: I see. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954376/linq-to-entities-dynamic-select-for-specify-columns) and use the library.